# Using Application.Run in Excel VBA when workbook name contains spaces

Tags: vba, excel

```
Application.Run "MyWorkBook.xls!Macro1"
```

will work (run the macro called `Macro1` in the `MyWorkBook.xls` file).

```
Application.Run "My Work Book.xls!Macro1"
```

will not work (if the workbook name contains spaces, Excel says "the macro cannot be found").

I just spent hours figuring out that it's the spaces causing this problem...

**Is there a way around this without renaming the file?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use single quotes surrounding the filename:

```
Application.Run "'My Work Book.xls'!Macro1"
```

Comment: In general, its would be better to always use quotes when dealing with filenames in Excel

Comment: I found the same issue with dashes ('-') in the file name too. Very annoying

Comment: I have found the same applies to the Macro name if it has underscores (_) in it. For some reason, this just came about with users on Windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

Replace each of the spaces with `%20`

```
Application.Run "My%20Work%20Book.xls!Macro1"
```

Comment: I know this is all from a very long time ago, but I think this is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Yes this is definitely an answer to the question and not a comment, @ClaricPWI is just wrong here

Comment: Yes this is an answer, not as useful as @e.James's since you might replace a lot of characters

Answer (score 1):

Here **File_name** is the name of the file for which you want to call your macro

- Application.run "'"+File_name+"'"+"!Macro"
- Single quote in between double quote followed by + File_name + single quote in between double quote + your macro name in between double quotes.