# How to programmatically click an ActiveX button in another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I have a workbook `Wbk1` where a sheet has an ActiveX button.  I want to run the button's associated Sub from another workbook,`Wbk2`.  It's not practical to just copy the Sub's code into `Wbk2` because it in turn calls a bunch of functions from `Wbk1`.  I tried the following:

```
Sub pushButton()

Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim btn As MSForms.CommandButton

For Each obj In Wkb1.Sheets("testSheet").OLEObjects
  If TypeOf obj.Object Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
    set btn=obj.Object
    debug.print btn.Caption 'used to test whether or not For loop is picking up button
    obj.Activate
    SendKeys " "
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

It's not only an inelegant `SendKeys()` hack, but it doesn't work; the button gets focus but it doesn't get pushed.  I know that the For loop is correctly iterating through the objects, including the CommandButton, because I can pick up the caption for the button.  How can I click on this button (and thereby run its private Sub) from `Wbk2`?

EDIT: The actual filename in question is in the format 123A_1.0-2.0.xlsm. I think the periods are causing some trouble with regard to the solutions posted in comments and responses below, because when I remove the periods these techniques are successful.

Comment: If you know the name and location of the procedure then you can run it using `Application.Run` eg: `Application.Run "temp.xlsm!Sheet1.CommandButton1_Click"`  **EDIT** snap!

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks, this helps and when I run it with the filename "temp.xlsm", it works, but my actual file name is causing some problems because it has periods in it; see my response to nutsch's answer below.  Sorry for not including this in the question as originally posted.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136768/using-application-run-in-excel-vba-when-workbook-name-contains-spaces  You need to put single-quotes around the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just

```
Application.Run (wb1.Name & "!MacroName")
```

Comment: This helps, although I also need to include the sheet name where the button is, like `Application.Run "Wbk1!Sheet1.MacroName`.  The problem is that my actual workbook name has periods in it, e.g. Wbk1.0.xlsm.  Neither `Wbk1.0!Sheet1.MacroName` nor `Wbk1.0.xlsm!Sheet1.MacroName` successfully runs the procedure, as the first gives a "file cannot be found" error and the second gives a "Method 'Run' of object '_Application' failed" error.